# HashMap: containsKey() Not true when it should be?

Tags: java, encryption, jvm, hashmap, obfuscation

I am currently throwing an obfuscation program for school homework together. I am trying to make the program read a file and then create a new file that replaces each letter in the file with some a corresponding value that I pull from a `HashMap`. I set up a whole bunch of keys and values, but later in the process of writing the new file I try to check if the map contains a key before appending to the new `String`. The characters that are checked are in fact in the file that I am reading from to test, and the file is read correctly. Yet it fails with the `encryptionDict.containsKey()` (my hashmap) method.

I hope some Java expert can help me figure this out! I'm pretty clueless, I'm more of a C and D guy. The only thought that struck me was that it would be something like with Strings where `"foo" != "foo"`. But chars aren't objects.

The code is in a pastebin below, the key parts to look at is the class constructor, the method encrypt, and the method `initDictionary`, also can someone tell me why `HashMap<char, String>` is invalid, is it because I have to use an object?

The code: http://pastebin.com/NcHTHPfw

Comment: Did you use a debugger to see for which values it's failing?

Comment: Yeah it seems like Characters let's me skip the whole toCharArray() conversion

Comment: Eh no I didn't! I don't really know how to use the debugger. Just how to set a breakpoint etc. But I could try

Answer (score 6):

```
 private HashMap<char [], String> initDictionary() {
                HashMap<char [], String> d = new HashMap<char [], String>();

                d.put("a".toCharArray(), "!\"#¤");
                d.put("b".toCharArray(), "¤#\"!");
                d.put("c".toCharArray(), "\"#¤%");
                d.put("d".toCharArray(), "%¤#\"");
                d.put("e".toCharArray(), "#¤%&");
                d.put("f".toCharArray(), "&%¤#");
                d.put("g".toCharArray(), "¤%&/");
                d.put("h".toCharArray(), "/&%¤");
                d.put("i".toCharArray(), "%&/(");
                d.put("j".toCharArray(), "(/&%");
                d.put("k".toCharArray(), "&/()");
                d.put("l".toCharArray(), ")(/&");
                d.put("m".toCharArray(), "/()=");
                d.put("n".toCharArray(), "=)(/");
                d.put("o".toCharArray(), "()=?");
                d.put("p".toCharArray(), "?=)(");
                d.put("q".toCharArray(), ")=?!");
                d.put("r".toCharArray(), "!?=)");
                d.put("s".toCharArray(), "=?!\"");
                d.put("t".toCharArray(), "\"!?=");
                d.put("u".toCharArray(), "?!\"#");
                d.put("v".toCharArray(), "#\"!?");
                d.put("w".toCharArray(), ";:*^");
                d.put("x".toCharArray(), "^*:;");
                d.put("y".toCharArray(), ":*^>");
                d.put("z".toCharArray(), ">^*:");
// etc.
```

This is the problematic bit. You can't use arrays as hash keys in Java, as Array does not override the equals() and hashCode() methods.

The hashCode is used to find the correct bucket that contains the object you are looking for, and the equals() method compares the actual Objects. To make use of a HashMap, you need to override both of these methods in a sensible way, which you can't as array classes are final. So the only thing you could do if you absolutely insist on using char arrays is to use a wrapper class as key that has a char array.

Something like this:

```
public class Key {
    private final char[] array;

    public Key(final String string) {
        this(string.toCharArray());
    }
    public Key(final char[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public char[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Key key = (Key) o;

        if (!Arrays.equals(array, key.array)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return array != null ? Arrays.hashCode(array) : 0;
    }
}
```

Now you can have a `Map<Key, String>` and bould a `Key` Object from either a `String` or a `char[]`

Comment: `String` is a nice wrapper class for a char array :-)

Comment: Well I wanted to use char somehow because it is easy to call charAt on a String, it is a shame that there isn't a letterAt method or something!

Comment: @FrankPavageau true, but sometimes for security reasons, it is not legal to use String in sensitive methods because of String pooling etc.

Comment: *"You can't use arrays as hash keys in Java, as Array does not override the equals() and hashCode() methods."* That is not correct, you can use an array as a key in a map. Whether it's a good idea or not is a different discussion.

Comment: A `char` *is* a "letter". Are you confusing `char` and `byte`?

Comment: @assylias Grr. OK, you cannot *effectively* use arrays as hash keys.

Comment: @FrankPavageau what makes you think I am confusing the two?

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd That comment was for @BitPuffin wanting a `String.letterAt()` method. Sorry, I should have mentioned him explicitely.

Comment: That's an interesting implementation of CharBuffer you've got there :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that all `char[]` are unique, regardless of their contents.  It appears you really want to be using a String. Normally, you can write such a program without using a `char[]`

Instead you can write

```
private Map<Character, String> initDictionary() {
Map<Character, String> d = new HashMap<Character, String>();

d.put('a', "!\"#¤");
// etc
```

Comment: Or maybe `Character`, since it seems all the keys are actually single characters.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use arrays as key, they are not comparable, so when it compares the value does not match

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `HashMap<char [], String>`. This doesn't work as `.equals` and `.hashCode` are not defined on arrays. This simple test program verifiesthis:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  char[] a = String.valueOf('a').toCharArray();
  char[] b = String.valueOf('a').toCharArray();

  System.out.println(a.hashCode() == b.hashCode());
}
```

You could use a `Map<Character, String>` for your purposes. Another solution would be to use an array String[MAX_INDEX] which is indexed by `filecontent.charAt(index)` - this may be even simpler if MAX_INDEX is small (like 'z') in your case.